# [Run config]Extend classpath attribute via vm options

Tags: intellij-idea

What I'm trying to achive is to control via an enviroment varaible which additional ressource are on the classpath. Everything that I found on the internat suggests to add the required dependencies in the Project Structure view. But this is not practicable in my use case.
Is it possible to get the initial value of the classpath argument in the Run Configurations view? So I could do smth. like this in the vm options:
-cp classpathGeneratedByIntelliJ;${MY_ENVIROMENT_VAR}

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-160167

Comment: Thanks for this link. The solution to use -Xbootclasspath/p is suitable for my purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the wanted behaviour by adding the -Xbootclasspath/p=${MY_ENVIROMENT_VAR} to my vm options.